# Delete all files in a directory, except files with a specific string

Tags: arcpy, list

At the end of my script I want to delete all my temporarily created files in a directory. For this purpose I write all files into a list and look in the elements to see if it has the string "final.shp" or "final.tif". If it does, it remains and if not, the file should be deleted. This works fine with all shape files, only with the TIFFs my function fails. Unfortunately I can't find a way to solve the problem and I hope that someone can give me the decisive tip. Maybe you can tell me how to make the query case-insensitive?

```
def endreiniger(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            if not f.endswith('final.shp') or f.endswith('final.tif') or f.endswith('final.TIF'):
                arcpy.Delete_management(f)
            else:
                print(f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
if not f.endswith('final.shp') or f.endswith('final.tif'):
```

You are saying: if it does **not** end with `final.shp` or: if it **does** end with `final.tif`. Which can never be true.

Enclose in parenthesis:

```
if not (f.endswith('final.shp') or f.endswith('final.tif')):
```

Or pass a tuple to `endswith`:

```
import arcpy, os

path = r'C:\GIS\Data'
keep = ('final.shp','final.tif','final.TIF')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        if not f.endswith(keep):
            print('Deleting: {}'.format(os.path.join(root,f)))
            arcpy.Delete_management(os.path.join(root,f)) #You need to include root or file will not be found.
        else:
            print('Not deleting: {}'.format(f))
```

Comment: As @bixb0012 points out, this solution will destroy shapefiles by removing the `.dbf`, `.prj`, `.shx` and all other shapefile extension-linked files. It could also destroy the world files and other metadata associated with TIFF (non-GeoTIFF) files. I guess this is a "be careful what you ask for" situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is less an answer, until I update the code later, and more a warning for users that may come across this question.  Since [os.walk — Miscellaneous operating system interfaces - Python 3.11.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) is not data set aware, pairing it with
[Delete (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/delete.htm) in the manner as the OP will result in most of the files being deleted, including ones that should be saved.

For shape files, and even often TIF files, the data set isn't a single file but a collection of files.  Since `os.walk` isn't data set aware, it has no idea that `final.shp` belongs with `final.dbf`, `final.shx`, and other file.  Using `os.walk` to find files to delete works because `arcpy.management.Delete` is data set aware, and knows that deleting `final.shp` also means to delete the other files that make up a shape file.

An example:

```py
import arcpy
import os
import tempfile

print("{}".format("-"*80))
print("Create 'sample' and 'final' shape files and TIFFs....")
ws = tempfile.mkdtemp()
res = arcpy.management.CreateRasterDataset(ws, 'sample.tif')
res = arcpy.management.CreateRasterDataset(ws, 'final.tif')
res = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(ws, 'sample.shp')
res = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(ws, 'final.shp')


print("List files before deletion....\n{}\n".format(os.listdir(ws)))
print("Use os.walk() to find and delete 'final' files")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ws):
    for file in files:
        if file.lower().endswith(("final.shp", "final.tif")):
            res = arcpy.management.Delete(os.path.join(root, file))
            print("... ArcPy Delete removed {}".format(file))

print("List files after deletion....\n{}\n".format(os.listdir(ws)))
print("{}".format("-"*80))
```

yields:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create 'sample' and 'final' shape files and TIFFs....
List files before deletion....
['final.cpg', 'final.dbf', 'final.shp', 'final.shp.xml', 'final.shx', 'final.tfw', 'final.tif', 'final.tif.xml', 'sample.cpg', 'sample.dbf', 'sample.shp', 'sample.shp.xml', 'sample.shx', 'sample.tfw', 'sample.tif', 'sample.tif.xml']

Use os.walk() to find and delete 'final' files
... ArcPy Delete removed final.shp
... ArcPy Delete removed final.tif
List files after deletion....
['sample.cpg', 'sample.dbf', 'sample.shp', 'sample.shp.xml', 'sample.shx', 'sample.tfw', 'sample.tif', 'sample.tif.xml']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

One can see that simply passing `final.shp` and `final.tif` to `arcpy.management.Delete` results in those *data sets* getting removed because ArcPy is data set aware for these types of data sets.

Whereas using `os.walk` to find specific data sets to delete works, the opposite does not work where you want to delete everything but some data sets.

```py
import arcpy
import os
import tempfile

print("{}".format("-"*80))
print("Create 'sample' and 'final' shape files and TIFFs....")
ws = tempfile.mkdtemp()
res = arcpy.management.CreateRasterDataset(ws, 'sample.tif')
res = arcpy.management.CreateRasterDataset(ws, 'final.tif')
res = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(ws, 'sample.shp')
res = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(ws, 'final.shp')


print("List files before deletion....\n{}\n".format(os.listdir(ws)))
print("Use os.walk() to find and delete other-than 'final' files")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ws):
    for file in files:
        if not file.lower().endswith(("final.shp", "final.tif")):
            res = arcpy.management.Delete(os.path.join(root, file))
            print("... ArcPy Delete removed {}".format(file))

print("List files after deletion....\n{}\n".format(os.listdir(ws)))
print("{}".format("-"*80))
```

yields:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create 'sample' and 'final' shape files and TIFFs....
List files before deletion....
['final.cpg', 'final.dbf', 'final.shp', 'final.shp.xml', 'final.shx', 'final.tfw', 'final.tif', 'final.tif.xml', 'sample.cpg', 'sample.dbf', 'sample.shp', 'sample.shp.xml', 'sample.shx', 'sample.tfw', 'sample.tif', 'sample.tif.xml']

Use os.walk() to find and delete other-than 'final' files
... ArcPy Delete removed final.cpg
... ArcPy Delete removed final.dbf
... ArcPy Delete removed final.shp.xml
... ArcPy Delete removed final.shx
... ArcPy Delete removed final.tfw
... ArcPy Delete removed final.tif.xml
... ArcPy Delete removed sample.cpg
... ArcPy Delete removed sample.dbf
... ArcPy Delete removed sample.shp
... ArcPy Delete removed sample.shp.xml
... ArcPy Delete removed sample.shx
... ArcPy Delete removed sample.tfw
... ArcPy Delete removed sample.tif
... ArcPy Delete removed sample.tif.xml
List files after deletion....
['final.tif']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

One can see that using `os.walk` to find files to save does not work because it is not data set aware, and passing `final.dbf` to `arcpy.management.Delete` actually results in all the files, including `final.shp` getting deleted.  For TIF files, deleting the auxiliary files doesn't remove the TIF file itself, but it still deletes files that may have critical information for the raster data set.